# Storybook controls disapers when wrapping component in HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I have a Component in my storybook that have some controls and looks like this in the UI
[image]

But when i wrap my component in a HOC `export default withAlign(Avatar)` it breaks and does not display any controls, and the controls section is replaces with the following text: `No inputs found for this component. Read the docs`

Here is my code for the stories
index.stories.tsx

```
import { Meta } from '@storybook/react'
import Avatar from '../Avatar'
export { AvatarColor } from './AvatarColor.stories'
export { Default } from './AvatarDefault.stories'

export default {
  title: 'Components/Avatar',
  component: Avatar,
  parameters: {
    docs: {
      description: {
        component: `An Avatar is a graphical representation of a user, team, or entity.
        Avatar can display an image, icon, or initials, and supports various sizes and shapes.`,
      },
    },
  },
  decorators: [
    (Story) => (
      <div
        style={{
          display: 'flex',
          gap: '5px',
          flexWrap: 'wrap',
        }}
      >
        <Story />
      </div>
    ),
  ],
} as Meta
```

AvatarDefault.stories.tsx

```
import Avatar from '../Avatar'
import { AvatarProps } from '../Avatar.types'

export const Default = (props: Partial<AvatarProps>) => (
  <Avatar {...props}>Yooo</Avatar>
)
```

And then I have my type

```
import { HTMLAttributes } from 'react'

export type AvatarProps = Omit<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, 'color'> & {
  /**
   * The Size.
   *
   * @default 50
   */
  size?: number
  /**
   * The prop.
   * @default 80
   */
  someotherprop?: number
  /**
   * The color.
   *
   * @default "red"
   */
  color?: string
}
```

Any idea how I can display the controls when wrapping my component in a HOC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reactDocgen` from `@storybook/addon-docs` part of `@storybook/addon-essentials` Does not work with HoCs when you default export them.

Simply changing `export default withAlign(Avatar)`

To

```
const Avatar = withAlign(AvatarComponent)
export { Avatar }
```

Solved the issue and The component props and HoC props are displayed in the docs page